# How To get the sharepoint list items in new aspx page based on some condition

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have one List and two .aspx pages..and the first page is containing the one particular field items,and the second page is to display the list items based on first page field item....and now my question is how to redirect the second page based on first page field item

I want to retrieve items based on first page condition using javascript

Am new to sharepoint help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the field data from the first page using jQuery and send to the second page via QueryString, then in the second page, we can get the query string value and get the list items using REST API. The following simple example for your reference.

1.Create custom list "MyCustomList", add single line of text field "TestField".

2.Create a site page first.aspx and second.aspx.

3.In first.aspx page, add textbox and button, and add some jQuery code to get field value and redirect to second.aspx page when button click.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#getBtn").click(function(){
        var testField=$("#TestField").val();
        if(testField!=null){
            window.location.href="second.aspx?TestField="+testField;
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input id="TestField" type="text"/><input id="getBtn" type="button" value="GetItems"/>
```

4.In second.aspx page. The code like below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listName="CL0820";
    var testField=getQueryStringParameter("TestField");
    var filter="$filter=TestField eq '"+testField+"'";
    RetrieveListItems(listName,filter);
})
function RetrieveListItems(listName,filter){
    $("#ListData").html("");    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://sp2013/sites/team/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?"+filter,
        type: "GET",               
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var html="";
            html+="<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th></tr>";  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
              var item = data.d.results[i];  
              var id = item.ID;  
              var title = item.Title;
              html+="<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+title+"</td></tr>";  
            }
            html+"</table>";
            $("#ListData").html(html);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = window.location.href.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
</script>
<div id="ListData"/>
```